# Sign of diagonal product in determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Determin what sign does the product of Antidiagonal elements in $n\times n$ matrix have.

How does one go about solving this ? I know that ht sign depends on wheater the permutation is odd or even, but I dont know how to determine it for $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: Is the matrix antidiagonal?  Or does it have lots of entries?

Comment: Not specified, just any $n\times n$ matrix I would say ..

Comment: Does "antidiagonal" mean the entries $a_{j,n-j+1}$, $j=1,2,\dots,n$? If so, do you see how to write the relevant permutation as a product of transpositions? and can you count how many transpositions? and then see when the permutation is odd, and when even?

Comment: Well the antidiagonal entries are simply speaking those from the top right corner to the bottom left corner. And no, I sadly dont think I know how to write the permutation as a product of transpositions...

Comment: what if it was a 2x2 matrix?  The sign (i.e. effect of sign function) is negative.  What if it was a 3x3 matrix -- I see positive number and recurse on sign from 2x2 matrix, so again negative.  What if it's a 4x4 matrix?  This problem is designed for recursion and using the recursive definition of the determinant.

Comment: Do you know *any* way to write the relevant permutation, mr.p? or even to describe it in words? Do you know what permutation I am referring to? [and do you see that your "top right corner to bottom left corner" is the same thing as my $a_{j,n-j+1}$, $j=1,2,\dots,n$?]

Comment: Are you still here, mr.p?

Comment: Sorry Gerry, had some Corona lockdown trouble to deal with. Anyway, I do see that it actually is the same, but I have to say I dont really know how to write the permutation.

Comment: Then it seems to me that your real problem isn't about determinants, it's about permutations, how you write them, what *even* and *odd* mean in the context of permutations. Those are the questions you should be posting (or reading up on, as they are widely discussed in textbooks and websites and probably on this very website).

Comment: By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product of antidiagonal elements of the $n\times n$ matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ is given by

$$ a_{1,n}a_{2,n-1}\ldots a_{n-1,2}a_{n,1} $$

and to determine the sign from which to precede it for calculating the determinant of $A$, it is necessary to examine the permutation

$$ \left(\begin{array}{ccccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & \ldots & n-2 & n-1 & n \\ n & n-1 & n-2 & \ldots & 3 & 2 & 1\end{array}\right), $$

which we simply write

$$ (\begin{array}{ccccccc}  n & n-1 & n-2 & \ldots & 3 & 2 & 1 \end{array}), $$

and calculate how many transpositions it is necessary to operate on it to obtain the natural sequence. To do this, we note that to bring n to its natural position, n-1 exchanges are necessary with the elements on its right, thus obtaining the permutation

$$ (\begin{array}{ccccccc}  n-1 & n-2 & \ldots & 2 & 1 & n \end{array}). $$

In the same manner, $n-2$ exchanges are necessary to operate similarly on $n-1$ to obtain

$$ (\begin{array}{ccccccc}  n-2 & n-3 & \ldots & 2 & 1 & n-1 & n\end{array}) $$

etc. Ultimately it is clear that

$$ (n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots+2+1 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} $$

transpositions are needed in total to get the natural position of the indexes.

It follows that the sign we are looking for is given by $\;{(-1)^{\displaystyle n(n-1)/2}},\;$ 
thus getting the following table for all $n\geq 2$:

$$ \begin{array}{c} 2 && 3 && 4 && 5 && 6 && 7 && 8 && 9\\[1ex] - && - && + && + && - && - && + && +\end{array} \;\;\;\cdots $$